# Which implementation is better for code readability?

Tags: c++, readability

I have this code, which intention is just to initialize all zones to `false`:

```
Zone per_zone;
std::fill_n(per_zone.begin(), per_zone.capacity(), false);
System per_system;
std::fill_n(per_system.begin(), per_system.capacity(), per_zone);
std::fill_n(m_pMemory->TrackingZonesShowingLogicalParcels.begin(), m_pMemory->TrackingZonesShowingLogicalParcels.capacity(), per_system);
```

I refactored it with the following code, because I think it express more clearly the intention, and it's shorter.

```
for (auto& group : m_pMemory->TrackingZonesShowingLogicalParcels)
    for (auto& system : group)
        for (auto& zone : system)
            zone = false;
```

I really would use algorithms because I know that - in general - algorithms express intentions more clearly than for loops, but I don't think this is the case.

Am I wrong?
There is another approach that I could use to make the code more readable using the std algorithms?

Note that I don't care about performance for this.
Thank you.

Comment: What is `Zone`? it should have a constructor that takes the value and initializes elements so you can write `Zone per_zone{false};` or rather make it the default so all you have to write is `Zone per_zone;`

Comment: given the lack of context and details, "what is more readable" is purely opinion-based

Comment: `Zone` is a custom class that sadly does not have a constructor that takes a `bool`, I need to initialize its values in some way. I don't think that in this case it is really opinion based. It took me a while to understand what the first snippet does, I think that the second snippet is much clearer, but I could be wrong, that's why I am asking!

Comment: But I assume that you are suggesting that, if possible, I should change `Zone` to take a boolean in its constructor. In this way I would not need to have initializing code at all, right?

Comment: you think it is much cleaner. For someone used to algorithms but not to range based loops it can be just the opposite. Also the tag info says "Readability is a subjective parameter ..." acutally I don't know how one is supposed to use the tag without being offtopic

Comment: in general members should be initialzed by calling the constructor, if a class does not do that but you have to do something extra I would consider the class broken (well ok, in some special circumstances one has to make exceptions)

Comment: what is the underlying container? It looks a little odd that you have to set the elements to `false` in the first place. Maybe you don't actually need any of that?

Comment: Not related to your question, but I really hope `capacity()` is not the same thing as `std::vector<>::capacity()`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thank you, I think that you answered my question. The class is a custom container so I need to do this. But, as you said, if I am forced to write this ugly code is a problem in the class that I am using, initialization should be done in constructor.

Comment: Ideally, what you want is something like `m_pMemory->all_zones()` which returns a range to all of the zones.

Comment: Leaving the opinion-based part of readability aside. The two code blocks express two different things. They might result in the same thing, but if you read the code without having a closer look at the data types they have a different meaning. So if I should decide between those two (or any other solution) it would do that based on if the meaning of it is the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if OP can make use of C++20 or not, but the general idea of being able to iterate over a deeply nested hierarchy like this is precisely what `std::ranges::join_view` is for.

Using it, you can separate the aggregation of the the target elements and the operation on the aggregated references as two distinct operations:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Memory {
    using System = std::vector<int>;
    using Group = std::vector<System>;
    std::vector<Group> TrackingZonesShowingLogicalParcels;
};

 void foo(Memory* m_pMemory)
 {
     // Create a view representing all of the zones
     auto all_zones = m_pMemory->TrackingZonesShowingLogicalParcels | std::views::join | std::views::join;

     // use that view as if it was a container.
     std::fill(all_zones.begin(), all_zones.end(), 1);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sadly I cannot use c++20 standart atm, but I have access to boost libraries. Have you some suggestion for using this approach with boost ranges?

Comment: @Dundo If you can bring in the header-only ranges-v3, then it should just be a drop-in replacement. Not sure about boost ranges though.